# Why does the crypto_box functionality in NaCl library expose the nonce to the programmer?

Tags: nonce

The idea of [crypto_box API in NaCl library](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html) is to shield the programmer away from the technical details and provide easy to use functions for encrypting and encrypting messages.

Given what I've just written, I do not understand why the idea of *nonce* is exposed in this API. Explaining what nonce is and how to use it takes up a significant portion of the documentation and it is quite possible to get this wrong. Wouldn't it be better to just generate a random bytestring under the covers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [article on NaCl](http://cr.yp.to/highspeed/coolnacl-20120725.pdf) by its authors touches this subject. I'll quote here the relevant bit:

> **Nonces**. The crypto_box API leaves nonce generation to the caller. This
> is not meant to suggest that nonce generation is not part of the
> cryptographer’s job; on the contrary, we believe that cryptographers
> should take responsibility not just for nonces but also for other
> security aspects of high-level network protocols. The exposure of
> nonces simply reflects the fact that nonces are integrated into
> high-level protocols in different ways.
>
> It might seem simplest to
> always generate a random 24-byte nonce n, and to transmit this nonce
> as part of the authenticated ciphertext; 24-byte random strings have
> negligible chance of colliding. If ciphertexts are long then one can
> tolerate the costs of generating this randomness and of expanding each
> ciphertext by 24 bytes. However, random nonces do nothing to stop the
> simplest type of forgery, namely a replay. One standard strategy to
> prevent replays is to include an increasing number in each packet and
> to reject any packet whose number is not larger than the number in the
> last verified packet; using these sequence numbers as nonces is
> simpler than giving each packet a number and a random nonce. On the
> other hand, choosing public nonces as sequence numbers means giving
> away traffic information that would otherwise be somewhat more
> expensive for an attacker to collect. Several different solutions
> appear in the literature; constraints on nonce generation are often
> tied directly to questions of the security and privacy that users
> expect.
>
> Current applications of NaCl, such as DNSCurve and CurveCP,
> have different requirements regarding nonces, replays, forward
> secrecy, and many other security issues at a higher level than the
> crypto_box API. A nonceless API would require higher-level
> complications in all of these applications, and would not simplify
> their security analysis.